# How do I access the history object outside of components (using HashRouter)?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've read react-router documentation here: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/FAQ.md#how-do-i-access-the-history-object-outside-of-components

And the article solves the solution using Router; however, I need to use the HashRouter in my implementation (per business case).  Is there any way of making this happen?

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before to implement storing some page history. You will want to do this during your react dom render.

I just directly added functions to the history object itself. I don't have experience using the HashRouter, but this is something I've done with the BrowserRouter. You can even pass in the redux store to your createHistory function or an instance of whatever 'business' service you may need. Or it may make sense to even pass the history instance itself to your business service.

Example:

```
import React from "react";

import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import { Router, matchPath } from "react-router-dom";

import App from "./App";

// Function that handles creation of our redux store
import createStore from "./store";

// Function that handles creation of our custom history
// Would normally outsource this to its own file to be imported
const getFullURL = (location) => location.pathname + location.search;
export default (limit = 25) => {
  const history = createBrowserHistory();

  // Extend our history with a stack
  history.stack = [getFullURL(history.location)];

  // Add ability to listen to our history
  history.listen((location, action) => {
    const url = getFullURL(location);

    if (action === "REPLACE") {
      history.stack.pop();
    }

    history.stack.push(url);

    if (history.stack.length > limit) {
      history.stack.shift();
    }
  });

  // Extend our history with a function to go back to the
  //  most recent match route
  history.goToMostRecent = (routes, defaultPath = false) => {
    for (let i = history.stack.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
      const path = history.stack[i];
      const strippedPath = path.split("?")[0];
      for (let j = 0; j < routes.length; j++) {
        const route = routes[j];
        const match = matchPath(strippedPath, {
          exact: true,
          path: route,
        });

        if (match) {
          history.push(path);
          return;
        }
      }
    }

    if (defaultPath) history.push(defaultPath);
  };

  return history;
};

const store = createStore();

// custom history with stack + extra actions
// could even pass in our store if we needed to access it for some reason
const history = createHistory();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```